# Success callback for Azure mobile services `push.apns.send`

Tags: javascript, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

`push.apns.send` method does not call `success` callback. So in case of successful execution we cannot determine when this operation was completed.

Here is my code (it is a part of a server-side script which runs on insert event for one of that data tables):

```
  push.apns.send(message.deviceToken, {
    alert: message.alert,
    badge: message.badge,
    sound: message.sound,
    payload: {
      message: message.alert,
      appID: message.appID
    }
  }, {
    success: function(resp) {
      console.log(resp)
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  })
```

`error` callback works. For example when I pass invalid `deviceToken`, I can see error message in log. But in case of successful execution, there's nothing in the log. It seems that it does not call `success` callback at all.

It is not shown in this example, but in my case I need `success` callback to change the status of the record and save it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's how the [Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) works. Basically, under the covers a TCP connection is opened to APNS and the bytes (properly formatted) corresponding to your message are sent to the service. If the push succeeds, the APNS doesn't send any response back. If it doesn't, it may respond immediately (which is the case where the error callback is called), or it may not - and later when you try to access the feedback service it *may* tell you that there was an error.

So, given that there's no reliable way to tell the caller of `push.apns.send` that the push succeeded, the team decided that it doesn't make sense to add a `success` callback (which would give a false impression that the push was successful).

One heuristic which you may want to use is to first send the push, then wait (`setTimeout`) for some time, and if the error callback is not invoked, then you assume that the push was successful. Notice that it's not 100% accurate as I mentioned above, but it may be enough for your scenario.

Comment: Now I see, Thanks for the clarification and a workaround. I think it will work for us.

Answer (score -2):

Change following in you code it will work.

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data)
},
```